# Kivy: Can I pass a Popup content using kivy language?

Tags: python, popup, kivy

I'm trying to add a content from a Popup directly into the '.kv' file.

```
<PresentationScreen>:
name: 'presentation'
FloatLayout:
    PageLayout:
        Popup:
            title: 'Apresenta\u00e7\u00e3o'
            title_align: 'center'
            title_font: 'images/fonts/CaviarDreams_BoldItalic.ttf'
            title_size: 18
            separator_color: 0.988, 0.776, 0.388, 1
```

I can't find an executable way to add a Label as content inside this code. 
The only way is if I add a straight foward Label into the screen (see below code), but that's not good at all because the text doesn't follow screen changes when I do it like that.

```
<PresentationScreen>:
name: 'presentation'
FloatLayout:
    PageLayout:
        Popup:
            title: 'Apresenta\u00e7\u00e3o'
            title_align: 'center'
            title_font: 'images/fonts/CaviarDreams_BoldItalic.ttf'
            title_size: 18
            separator_color: 0.988, 0.776, 0.388, 1
            Label:
                text: 'Hi'
```

Comment: You need to provide more information (like a [mcve]). But why can't you just add the `Label` using a method in your `PresentationScreen` class?

Comment: I though I wasn't going to be able to do this (kinda new in programming and confused about the whole python/kivy mix). But I did as you told using a method!! Thanks man!